# How to return element value in an array by index position?

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to print i getting error msg.
Question- Need StrArray and ConArray elements value by position of pos.

```
Dim RMSIND As Integer, STRIND As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim arra As Variant
Dim StrArray As Variant
Dim ConArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim ColAdd1 As Long
Dim ColAdd2 As Long
Dim Col_1 As Range
Dim Col_2 As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim pos

 Set Col_1 = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("Scheme")
 ColAdd1 = Col_1.Column

Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, ColAdd1), Cells(lRow, ColAdd1))
For Each Cell In rng1
  If Cell.Value = "RMS IND" Then
          arra = VBA.Array(1001, 1011, 1021, 1031, 1041, 1051, 2001, 2011, 3001, 3011, 3021, 3031, 3041, 3051, 3061, 4001, 4011, 4021, 4031, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5011, 5021, 5022, 5023, 5031, 5032, 5033, 6001, 6011, 6012, 6013, 6021, 6031, 6032, 6033, 6041, 6042, 6043, 7001, 7011, 7021, 7031, 7041, 7051, 7061, 7071, 7081, 7082, 7083)
          RMSIND = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            pos = Application.Match(RMSIND, arra, False)
            If Not IsError(pos) Then
                StrArray = VBA.Array(16, 20, 10, 18, 14, 14, 15, 24, 33, 23, 42, 24, 34, 30, 25, 15, 8, 8, 15, 15, 15, 15, 44, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 100, 10, 10, 10, 40, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 11, 40, 25, 62, 61, 100, 85, 0, 75, 75, 75)
                ConArray = VBA.Array(84, 80, 90, 82, 86, 86, 85, 76, 67, 77, 58, 76, 66, 70, 75, 85, 92, 92, 85, 85, 85, 85, 56, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 0, 90, 90, 90, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, 60, 75, 38, 39, 0, 15, 100, 25, 25, 25)
                 i = StrArray(pos)
                 MsgBox (i)
'Unable to print i getting error msg.
'Q- Need StrArray and ConArray elements value at position of pos.

'Unable to print i getting error msg.
'Q- Need StrArray and ConArray elements value in an array by position of pos.
```

Comment: What is the value of `pos` when it fails?  And what's the error message.

Comment: Run time error '9': subscript out of range

Comment: Where have you specified `lRow`?

Comment: Dim lRow As Long, Dim lColumn As Long, Dim ColAdd2 As Long, Dim Col_2 As Range, Dim rng2 As Range: These variables are not in use due to error.

Answer (score 0):

`Match()` returns a *1-based index*, but your arrays are *zero-based*, so if the match occurs on the last element of `arra` then `pos` will be out of bounds on `StrArray` (ie. it will be ubound +1)

...and even if you did not get an error, the value returned from `StrArray` would be wrong

A smaller version to illustrate:

```
Dim arra,  pos, pos2, StrArray

arra = VBA.Array(1001, 1011, 1021, 1031, 1041)
StrArray = VBA.Array(16, 20, 10, 18, 14)

pos = Application.Match(1041, arra, False)   '>> 5
pos2 = Application.Match(1031, arra, False)  '>> 4

'skipping the error checking for pos    

Debug.Print StrArray(pos)      '>> "subscript out of range" [pos=5 but ubound(StrArray)=4]
Debug.Print StrArray(pos2)     '>> 14 [should be 18]

Debug.Print StrArray(pos - 1)  '>> 14 as expected
Debug.Print StrArray(pos2 - 1) '>> 18 as expected
```